# Cannot unpickle pickled object

Tags: python, python-3.4, pickle

Running Python 3.4.3 on linux.

```
import pickle
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
pickled = pickle.dumps(context)
unpickled = pickle.loads(pickled)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    unpickled = pickle.loads(pickled)
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'protocol'
```

I don't do much pickling, so forgive me if this is well know.

I had a bit of a look around the only I found [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#pickle) about **pickle** in the [*What's new In Python 3.4*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#what-s-new-in-python-3-4) which suggests this should work. Other than that just issues pickling between different python versions.

I also tried setting `pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` but this didn't help either.

(BTW I've already worked around this issue but I'm curious why it does not work.)

Comment: You say you've already solved the issue, so why not share the solution? Maybe it could shed some light.

Comment: It does not work because `SSLContext` currently lacks pickle support.

Comment: The linked change mentioning `pickle` only says the new protocol now supports "classes whose \_\_new\_\_() method takes _keyword-only arguments_". The error message says "missing 1 required _positional argument_". (emphasis mine,)

Comment: @ForceBru, oh I just worked around it by making the ssl context not be part of the object that gets pickled. Looks like this is a pretty well known issue though (and proper solutions exist, I just don't know my pickle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes that take extra arguments to `__new__` need to [provide a `__getnewargs__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) to tell pickle what the extra arguments are.

You can monkey-patch `SSLProtocol` to add a `__getnewargs__` method:

```
ssl.SSLContext.__getnewargs__ = lambda self: (self.protocol,)
```

The new feature of pickle in Python 3.4 is that it [also supports a `__getnewargs_ex__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs_ex__) that can supply keyword arguments for `__new__`; but classes still need to provide `__getnewargs__` and/or `__getnewargs_ex__` themselves.